# Flipped bones with pivot constraint isn't working as expected

Tags: armature, bones, bone.constraints

I feel like this is a bug but I am still asking, just in case. Anyways, I am making a model for a game I am working on called Nightly Escape. Sorry for the plugging there. But to the point, I am trying to make a large cabinet so the player could hide. However, when trying to add pivot constraints to my bones of the armature so I can animate the doors opening, it messes up. I mean messes up largely. I uploaded a video on Youtube to help explain as it is hard to explain as text. Plug it pretty much says it in the video.

https://youtu.be/mBAL9TEkOdQ

I will also share my blend file. However, it will show just the armature, not my cabinet I made. I like to keep things classified.

I figured out it happens when I flip the bones. If I rotate them back to normal, it works. However, I am still not sure why.

[image]